# Is the function of the complex conjugate differentiable?

Tags: complex-analysis

I've to prove that if I know $f(z)$ is differentiable in $ a \in \Bbb C $ , that also $g(z) = \overline {f(\bar z)}$ is differentiable in $\bar a$.

So I tried to use Cauchy–Riemann equations. If I know that $ f(z) $ differentiable so I can say:
$f(z) = f(x,y) = u(x,y)+i \cdot v(x,y)$, and define $ a = x_0+iy_0 $, and say that:
$ \dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x}(x_0,y_0) =  \dfrac{\partial v}{\partial y}(x_0,y_0) $  and
$ \dfrac{\partial u}{\partial y}(x_0,y_0) =  -\dfrac{\partial v}{\partial x}(x_0,y_0) $.

From here I wanted to continue by writing similar result for $ g(z) $. But how can I write:
$ g(z)=\overline{ f(\bar z) }$?
Does $$ g(z) = \overline { f(\bar z) }  =  u(x,-y)-i \cdot v(x,-y) $$ is correct?

Comment: It makes more sense to just apply the definition of derivative.

Answer (score 1):

Counter example: let $f(z)=z$. Then $g(z):=f(\overline{z})=\overline{z}.$

If $ a \in \mathbb C$, then $g$ is not (complex) differentiable at $a$.

Comment: But i want to show that if $ f(z) $ is differentiable in $ a $ then $ f(\bar z) $ is differentiable in $ \bar a$

Comment: Then, as Fred just told you, you "want to show" something that is NOT TRUE!

Comment: I sorry, I've edited my first post, I have been a little bit wrong on the details of the question. Anyways it has to be true because the assignment says that I've to prove it

Comment: OP asks about the conjugate of the function of the conjugate.

Comment: @KonstantinKhrizman, questions *do* get it wrong, or have typos in them...